# Trigger a user specific weekly task list update via email

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, task-list

I have a list of tasks assigned to multiple users and I am trying to trigger a weekly flow that emails a user and shows all of the uncompleted tasks that are assigned to them. I have started with a recurrence step that runs once a week.

[image]

But I am not sure how to configure the next steps (Get Items (I think?) and Email). It is confusing because the flow needs to check each user and compile a list of tasks that have been assigned to them AND are incomplete. I have included an example of the list below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Get Items action have a filed called Filter Query which allows you to filter all the list items you need and get them. Mostly the follow will be like Recurrence->Get Items->Apply to each including send emails. Here are some articles talking about using filter query. Have a look at them try with your list.

https://tahoeninjas.blog/2019/07/03/using-the-sharepoint-getitems-action-in-flow/

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/apply-filter-query-with-get-items-sharepoint-action-in-microsoft-flow/

https://www.chakkaradeep.com/2018/05/01/deep-dive-into-get-items-and-get-files-sharepoint-actions-in-microsoft-flow/

Comment: Thanks. I am struggling because how am I meant to filter the list to show all of the tasks categorised by who they are assigned to.

Comment: @JohnGIS Check this: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/How-to-filter-get-items-properly-for-people/td-p/291195   You can try to use the filter array action to form your filter query.